# markov chain testing and implementation

Tags: c, algorithm

So, I want to read in a text file with random numbers and create the suffix list using those numbers. it basically needs to reproduce the text given in "alice30.txt" using the algorithm. The code that I have right now looks like this. It compiles fine but doesn't create an output file for me. I need to reverse the array of the suffix so the output is correct. any help will be greatly appreciated. i have declared all the necessary functions like emalloc in the eprint f header file.

```
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include "eprintf.h"

  enum {
NPREF   = 2,    /* number of prefix words */
NHASH   = 4093, /* size of state hash table array */
MAXGEN  = 10000 /* maximum words generated */
   };

 typedef struct State State;
 typedef struct Suffix Suffix;

    struct State {  /* prefix + suffix list */
char    *pref[NPREF];   /* prefix words */
Suffix  *suf;           /* list of suffixes */
State   *next;          /* next in hash table */
    };

   struct Suffix {  /* list of suffixes */
char    *word;          /* suffix */
Suffix  *next;          /* next in list of suffixes */
  };

 State  *lookup(char *prefix[], int create);
 void   build(char *prefix[], FILE* myfile); /*assing the input stream*/
 void       generate(int nwords, int random_num[], FILE* outfile);
  /* passing the array and the output stream*/
 void   add(char *prefix[], char *word);

 State  *statetab[NHASH];   /* hash table of states */

 char NONWORD[] = "\n";  /* cannot appear as real word */


  /* markov main: markov-chain random text generation */
 int main(void)
 {
int i, nwords = MAXGEN;
char *prefix[NPREF];        /* current input prefix */

FILE* random_reader;
FILE* myfile;
FILE* outfile;

int c;
int element;
int random_num[10000];
char* line;
int j=0;
random_reader = fopen("../random_num.txt","r");
myfile = fopen("../alice30.txt","r");
outfile = fopen("../output/markov_c_out.txt","w");
while(fgets(line,20,random_reader)!=NULL)
{
    sscanf(line,"%o",&element);
    random_num[j]= element;
    j++;
}

setprogname("markov");


for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++) /* set up initial prefix */
    prefix[i] = NONWORD;
build(prefix, myfile);
add(prefix, NONWORD);
generate(nwords, random_num, outfile); // calling the updated function
return 0;
    }   

   const int MULTIPLIER = 31;  /* for hash() */

   /* hash: compute hash value for array of NPREF strings */
     unsigned int hash(char *s[NPREF])
   {
unsigned int h;
unsigned char *p;
int i;

h = 0;
for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
    for (p = (unsigned char *) s[i]; *p != '\0'; p++)
        h = MULTIPLIER * h + *p;
return h % NHASH;
     }

  /* lookup: search for prefix; create if requested. */
   /*  returns pointer if present or created; NULL if not. */
     /*  creation doesn't strdup so strings mustn't change later. */
     State* lookup(char *prefix[NPREF], int create)
   {
int i, h;
State *sp;

h = hash(prefix);
for (sp = statetab[h]; sp != NULL; sp = sp->next) {
    for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
        if (strcmp(prefix[i], sp->pref[i]) != 0)
            break;
    if (i == NPREF)     /* found it */
        return sp;
}
if (create) {
    sp = (State *) emalloc(sizeof(State));
    for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++)
        sp->pref[i] = prefix[i];
    sp->suf = NULL;
    sp->next = statetab[h];
    statetab[h] = sp;
}
return sp;
      }

     /* addsuffix: add to state. suffix must not change later */
      void addsuffix(State *sp, char *suffix)
     {
Suffix *suf;

suf = (Suffix *) emalloc(sizeof(Suffix));
suf->word = suffix;
suf->next = sp->suf;
sp->suf = suf;
  }

     /* add: add word to suffix list, update prefix */
   void add(char *prefix[NPREF], char *suffix)
    {
State *sp;

sp = lookup(prefix, 1);  /* create if not found */
addsuffix(sp, suffix);
/* move the words down the prefix */
memmove(prefix, prefix+1, (NPREF-1)*sizeof(prefix[0]));
prefix[NPREF-1] = suffix;
        }

       /* build: read input, build prefix table */
         void build(char *prefix[NPREF], FILE *myfile)
        {
char buf[100], fmt[10];

/* create a format string; %s could overflow buf */
sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", sizeof(buf)-1);
while (fscanf(myfile, fmt, buf) != EOF)
    add(prefix, estrdup(buf));
         }

       /* generate: produce output, one word per line */
     void generate(int nwords, int random_num[], FILE* outfile)
     {
State *sp;
Suffix *suf;
char *prefix[NPREF], *w;
int i, nmatch;

for (i = 0; i < NPREF; i++) /* reset initial prefix */
    prefix[i] = NONWORD;

for (i = 0; i < nwords; i++) {
    sp = lookup(prefix, 0);
    if (sp == NULL)
        eprintf("internal error: lookup failed");
    nmatch = 0;
    for (suf = sp->suf; suf != NULL; suf = suf->next)
        if (random_num[i] % ++nmatch == 0) /*using the elements of the array  */
            w = suf->word;
    if (nmatch == 0)
        eprintf("internal error: no suffix %d %s", i, prefix[0]);
    if (strcmp(w, NONWORD) == 0)
        break;

    fprintf(outfile, w);
    memmove(prefix, prefix+1, (NPREF-1)*sizeof(prefix[0]));
    prefix[NPREF-1] = w;

}
```

}

Comment: This is homework.  You should tag it as such.

Comment: @Amir Use of the homework tag is discouraged now. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `fgets` an uninitialized variable.

You declare this:

```
char* line;
```

and later call:

```
while(fgets(line,20,random_reader)!=NULL)
```

but you never created space to store the string read.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the algorithm used in your code, your program does not generate output because you are not closing your files. Add to the end of your main function the following lines:

```
fclose( outfile );
fclose( myfile );
fclose( randome_reader );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm sure there is something wrong with the algorithm too though. I think i'm updating the random_num array properly so i should get an output, albeit maybe incorrect.